# Not showing colors in material mode

Tags: modeling

I'm making this alarm clock, and after going to material mode from solid, it's not showing me the colors. Mine is like this [image]
And colors are definitely there [image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you applied any materials to your objects? If so do they have any color assigned?

Comment: Yes I have. I'm doing it from an youtube video and followed the instructions there. At first it showed colors, then I think pressed something, cause suddenly they r gone

Comment: help anyone????

Comment: Well, Aisha, numbers are rendering in black... so colors are there... but could you upload your file in order to check if the same occurs in another environment? Please use this link to do that: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Colors are definitely there. I've edited the question and added a new screenshot. Check it please and am trying to upload the file in the link you gave. taking too long.

Comment: I am making a guess there that there is a separate viewport color you did not change. It's how blender works dont ask me why XD.

Comment: @lemon here's the file link [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2960" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2960/)

Comment: Here is the direct result for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hQmK.jpg... so I don't know how to help... : (

Comment: No prob. Problem solved. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here is the box you need to change. I think you got it wrong way round when you explain your issue too. You went from material to solid mode ... not the other way round I guess.

Basically, what's happening here is that. The solid mode is an opengl operation so it uses a different color operation for showing color on screen. Where material mode takes the material color into consideration. Solid mode are usually usually a quick way to set up simple color to work on the models before heading onto material creation.

[image]

And here is the same file with the colors changed!

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you and no, as I said I went from solid to material

Comment: ...mmm... I just don't get the point.. If I upload the file from @AishaGalaxy (in the comments above) I get the exact same result as the blend file in your answer. So.. why is it different for her? I'm not saying your answer is wrong.. just I do not understand it!

Comment: Color of the model in the viewport in material shading mode is driven with node settings; it doesn't depend on Viewport Color option in Settings rollout, so hard to guess the question then.

Comment: If you go to solid mode in her file ... all the color of the object are grey. When I looked at the first image she posted, it's a mystery to me since it's showing that she is indeed in material mode. I have no idea why in the first place the colors did not show up. Maybe here installation of blender may have some issues to begin with. I am guessing

Comment: I am startled to find that alot of people downloaded blender from unofficial build sites that have poor reputation. These versions are sometimes part of the reason why people experience issue with their installations.

Comment: ok... I've often noticed that Cycles material mode is a bit hazardous... main thing: the OP has her answer!

Comment: FYI I downloaded it from blender official site -_- and problem happened cause I accidentally pressed something I shouldn't have. At first it did show me colors. Anyways appreciate all the help

Comment: @AishaGalaxy Do tell us what did you accidentally press it would be helpful for future question seekers